# If value in select option is lower than in second select option, then change option

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to achieve:

If I select "16" in first select box and bigger value in second, for example "17", then in second select automatically changing to "16".

Just if value in first select box is lower than second, always change to same values, for example 16 to 16, 18 to 18.

```
<select id="from_age_js" name="from_age" class="select-advertise-style">
   <option value="f13">13</option>
   <option value="f14">14</option>
   <option value="f15">15</option>
   <option value="f16">16</option>
   <option value="f17">17</option>
   <option value="f18" selected>18</option>
   <option value="f19">19</option>
   <option value="f20">20</option>
</select>
—
<select id="to_age_js" name="to_age" class="select-advertise-style">
   <option value="t13">13</option>
   <option value="t14">14</option>
   <option value="t15">15</option>
   <option value="t16">16</option>
   <option value="t17">17</option>
   <option value="t18">18</option>
   <option value="t20" selected>20+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what you've tried so far??

Comment: I found something like that http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/ and http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/3/ but it's quite different.

Comment: I think you just have to detect the changes in the first select, and get and store the value. Then, when there’s a change in your second select, you compare the option value with the first one. If it’s lower, then add « selected » attribute to the good option.

Comment: I currently explained  that in this question. If you could write a code with the explanation because I just learning JS, I will approve your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy one, in your case, with pure javascript, I would do something like this:

```
function checkit()
{

//Store the two dropdowns for easy reference
var fromAge = document.getElementById('from_age_js');
var toAge = document.getElementById('to_age_js');

//Verify if the toAge value is minor, to see if the conditional code will be executed
if( fromAge.options[fromAge.selectedIndex].value > 
        toAge.options[toAge.selectedIndex].value)
    {
        //In that case, match the values to be the same...
        document.getElementById('to_age_js').value =
      fromAge.options[fromAge.selectedIndex].value;
    }

}
```

And you just have to add that function to where you want it to be called. I would choose to add the `onchange` event from Javascript within the select dropdowns. Like this:

```
<select id="from_age_js" name="from_age" class="select-advertise-style" onchange="checkit();">
```

You can see a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8cmad3tz/19/

Comment: @Konrad glad to help!! Have a nice day.